# Getting old record using kendo grid with pagination inline editing and restored with click on sorting option

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-panelbar, kendo-sortable

I'm encountering an unexpected behavior with the Kendo Grid's sorting functionality in my application.

Here's the scenario:

```
I perform inline row editing for a record in the Kendo Grid with pagination.
Sorting the data by clicking a column header works as expected.
However, if I sort the data again after editing a row, the current index seems accurate, but the data object retrieved appears to be incorrect.
```

I want region behind this and their solution.